# Как удалить элемент созданный динамически при делегировании

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том, что у меня получается удалить либо все, либо 1 элемент, а по таргету не пойму в чем я недопонимаю.

[Ссылка на редактор с кодом](https://jsfiddle.net/9ef5j0h4/1/)

```js
let calcBtn = document.querySelector('.calc-button'),
  calcBody = document.querySelector('.calc-body'),
  calcDel = document.querySelectorAll('.calc-del'),
  calcItem = document.querySelectorAll('.calc-item');

function addItemCalc() {
  calcItem = document.createElement('div');
  calcItem.classList.add('calc-item');
  calcItem.innerHTML = `
      <iframe width="100%" height="480px" src="https://u021301.stepform.io/leAsBfh" 
      frameborder="0"></iframe>
     <button class="calc-del"></button>
     `;
  calcBody.before(calcItem);
}

function delItemCalc(item) {
  item.remove();

}

calcBody.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target && target.classList.contains('calc-button')) {
    addItemCalc();
  }
});

calcBody.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target && target.classList.contains('calc-del')) {
    calcItem.forEach((item, i) => {
      delItemCalc(item);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="calc-body">
  <div class="calc-item">
    <iframe width="100%" height="480px" src="https://u021301.stepform.io/leAsBfh" style="overflow: hidden" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <button class="calc-del"></button>
  </div>
  <!-- /.calc-tem -->

  <button class="calc-button">Добавить</button>
</div>
<!-- /.calc-body -->
```

Comment: Зачем проходите циклом по всем элементам?

Comment: да, цикл не нужен, let item = target.closest('.calc-item'); delItemCalc(item);

Comment: А ещё, у вас какой-то ужас твориться в функции `addItemCalc()`, получаете элементы, потом перезаписываете новым.. Чёт всё напутано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема в этой строчке:

```js
calcBody.before(calcItem);
```

Вы элемент подключаете не к `calcBody`, а перед ним - к `<body>`.

Раз используете шаблонные строки, то тогда и метод используйте более гибкий для вставки - `insertAdjacentHTML()` :

```js
let calcBtn = document.querySelector('.calc-button'),
  calcBody = document.querySelector('.calc-body'),
  calcDels = document.querySelectorAll('.calc-del'),
  calcItems = document.querySelectorAll('.calc-item');

function addItemCalc() {
  calcBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', `
    <div class="calc-item">
      <iframe width="100%" height="480px" src="https://u021301.stepform.io/leAsBfh" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <button class="calc-del">&times;</button>
    </div>
 `);
}

function delItemCalc(item) {
  item.remove();
}

calcBody.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target && target.classList.contains('calc-button')) {
    addItemCalc();
  } else if (target && target.classList.contains('calc-del')) {
    delItemCalc(target.parentElement);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="calc-body">
  <div class="calc-item">
    <iframe width="100%" height="480px" src="https://u021301.stepform.io/leAsBfh" style="overflow: hidden" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <button class="calc-del">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <!-- /.calc-tem -->
  <button class="calc-button">Добавить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сейчас еще раз просмотрю код для анализа

Comment: @DeniDove: правильнее было бы, вынести кнопку "Добавить" за пределы `<div class="calc-body">` - тогда можно добавлять новые блоки в конец `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', ...)` - так логичнее.

Comment: Благодарю)))), Вы спасли меня от выговора

Comment: @DeniDove: Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).

В `event.target` возвращается элемент, по которому произошёл ивент (в вашем случае `click` внутри элемента `.calc-body`)

Вы в условии отделили, что интересует вас только клик по элементу `.calc-del`, т.е. ваш `event.target` = `.calc-del` (условно).

Т.к. `.calc-del` лежит внутри элемента `.calc-item`, который вам нужно удалить, вам нужно от `event.target` вернуться наверх до `.calc-item` и удалить полученный `.calc-item`

Для поиска родителя с определённым селектором используйте метод [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
calcBody.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target && target.classList.contains('calc-del')) {
    delItemCalc(target.closest('.calc-item')) // target.closest('.calc-item').remove()
    // Код выше удалит родительский элемент `.calc-item` в котором был нажат `.calc-del`
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, за уделенное время, я ваше решение вставил, но почему то динамически созданный элемент не удалялся

Comment: Я написал в комментарии к вопросу, а так же [UModeL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1377638/221218) оставил ответ, с чем **ещё** вызвана проблема. Конкретно на ваш вопрос, отвечает мой ответ.

Comment: Возможно я Вас не совсем понял в силу не хватки знаний, дело в том, что я ваш вариант кода вставил и не сработало у меня, сейчас про таргет я понял что Вы имели ввиду, но изначально прочитав я не понял

Comment: Вот сейчас после изменений таргета , Ваш код заработал, надеюсь Вы не оскорбились, я просто не так силен как хотелось бы

Comment: Нет конечно же)